# open ./test/image_with_geotag.jpg: Access is denied

Tags: file, go, server

I'm trying to upload a file to a directory in my golang server.
the file I'm trying upload is received from a client without any errors.
However, for some reason I get the message on the title when I try creating a file to store the file I received.

my code:

```
r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)
id:= r.FormValue("id")
description:= r.FormValue("description")
fmt.Println(id)
fmt.Println(description)
file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer file.Close()
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", handler.Header)

//I suspect my error is here:

f, err:=os.OpenFile("./test/"+handler.Filename, os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0660);
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer f.Close()
io.Copy(f, file)



// I also tried:


//f, err := os.OpenFile("./test/"+handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
```

Note:
I get this message for any kind of file I try to upload

Update:
I made a little bit of progress,

somehow it will work when I write it like this:

```
 f, err:=os.OpenFile("./test/hello", os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0666);
```

but won't work when I write it like this(with the ending of the file):

```
 f, err:=os.OpenFile("./test/hello.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0666);
```

This is still a problem since I want to declare the kind of the file.

Also if I manually add a file called hello.txt to the folder it works so I don't think there is a windows permission issue.

Update again:
It only happens when using golang
I tried it with python and it worked
and only happens when I try to save it on c:
when I tried to save it on my flash drive (E:) it worked

could it be a permission problem in golang?
I also tried running as administrator, did'nt work

Comment: The user the binary is running as does not have permission to write to the filesystem location `./test` it looks like. I don't know what OS you are on, but if it's a UNIX-like you can try changing `./test/` to `/tmp/`, which is writable by anyone and everyone; if the problem goes away, you can be more confident that that indeed is the problem.

Comment: `os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE` o_append ? or o_truncate in case the file exists ?

Comment: I tried both your suggestions and they did'nt work, thanks for trying tho